# Points inside polygon including boundaries and vertices

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx, shapely

I have a list that contains all my points: `[(lon, lat), ...]` (The red, green and blue ones.) Now I want to check which points are part of my polygon and my result set should contain all blue and all green nodes.

I found http://geospatialpython.com/2011/08/point-in-polygon-2-on-line.html, shapely and matplotlib. The first isn't working at all. Shapely doesn't return all nodes I need. Matplotlib seems to consider points on boundary outside as well.

What is the cheapest way to get all (blue and) green nodes?

[image]

Comment: For `shapely`, you're wanting `poly.intersects(point)` instead of `poly.contains(point)`.

Comment: I don't know whether that is a bug, but when I use `shapely.geometry.Polygon()` to build a Polygon from my coordinates, `poly.intersects` and `poly.contains` work as expected! But `shapely.geometry.shape(feature['geometry']).contains(point)` just returns points that are part of the LineString. Maybe not a bug and my fault, but still somewhat confusing. Thank, you!

Comment: LinearRings (or a special type of LineString) and Polygons using the same coordinates are different things, so each are expected to contain different points. You seem to want a the intersection of the Polygon only.

Answer (score 0):

If you can interface with C++, I recommend the BOOST library additions of Luke Simonson and Gyuszi Suto.

Paper: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/polygon/doc/GTL_boostcon2009.pdf

Library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/polygon/doc/index.htm

These C++ additions run at "ludicrous speed", based on an elegant calculus of polygons that the authors developed.